# php mkdir() not working correctly

Tags: php, directory, mkdir

i have this code:

```
$a ="/Assets/ProductImages/oa/91/2239754/6/5151010073180_1_org_zoom.jpg";
$b ="/home/cfnic/domains/modmania.ir/public_html/image/Assets/ProductImages/oa/91/2239754/6/5151010073180_1_org_zoom.jpg";

$path = '';

$directories = explode('/', dirname($a));

foreach ($directories as $directory) {
    $path = $path . '/' . $directory;

    if (!is_dir('/home/cfnic/domains/modmania.ir/public_html/image/' . $path)) {
        mkdir('/home/cfnic/domains/modmania.ir/public_html/image/' . $path, 0777,true);
    }
}
```

it only create directory (Assets) and (ProductImages) 
what am i doing wrong?????

Comment: IS this a CLI script or a web based script

Comment: this is a PHP script

Comment: Yessss. But do you run it from the command line (CLI) or via a browser and web server?

Comment: via a browser and web server

Answer (score 0):

If your purpose is to create directories recursively you can use mkdir once .
This is the prototype of the function taken from the PHP manual

```
bool mkdir ( string $pathname [, int $mode = 0777 [, bool $recursive = false [, resource $context ]]] )
```

so the only thing you really need is:

```
mkdir('/home/cfnic/domains/modmania.ir/public_html/image'.dirname($a), 0777,true);
```

without the `foreach` loop.